# Visual artifacts when using MediaElement to play .mp4

Tags: wpf, video, mp4, mediaelement

I was looking to play some videos using WPF's `MediaElement` control, so as a starting point I took some sample XAML code from *WPF4 Unleashed* (page 661 if you want to look it up).

```
<Grid>
    <MediaElement Name="Video" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Button Name="PlayButton" Background="#55FFFFFF" Height="40">Play</Button>
        <Button Name="PauseButton" Background="#55FFFFFF" Height="40">Pause</Button>
        <Button Name="ResumeButton" Background="#55FFFFFF" Height="40">Resume</Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="PlayButton">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard Name="BeginStoryBoard">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <MediaTimeline Storyboard.TargetName="Video" Source="Path/To/Out.mp4"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="PauseButton">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BeginStoryBoard" />
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="ResumeButton">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BeginStoryBoard" />
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

I tried this snippet with 2 different videos, one I took from youtube and one I saved using [livestreamer](http://livestreamer.tanuki.se/en/latest/) (from a Twitch.tv stream). However, while both WMP and VLC could play both videos perfectly fine, the above XAML sample could not play the video from Livestreamer properly (there were a lot of visual artifacts, see below).

[image: Fixed version of the video on the left, Original on the right]

What's weird is according to an answer (to [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/53dc95aa-3f65-4c40-ad49-3d784a34c840/why-wpfmediaelement-differs-from-windows-media-player-in-playing-mp4-files)) on MSDN:

> 2, If WMP12 is provided, WPF mediaElement can play mp4 without any Codec Packs.

Speaking of codecs, I looked up the codec information for both videos using VLC:

Youtube:

- Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
- Resolution: 1920x1080
- Display Resolution: 1920x1080
- Frame rate: 29.970029

Livestreamer:

- Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (h264)

Now this shouldn't really matter because `MediaElement` should as I understand have the exact same behavior as WMP.

tl;dr; What is the proper way to play videos using WPF's MediaElement? (if not the one above)

P.S: If you must know, my end goal is to playback streams from twitch.tv and do some visual analysis on the video frames (using OpenCV or some other library).

P.P.S: If I use ffmpeg to re-render/re-encode/re-save the video using: `ffmpeg.exe -i Out.mp4 Out_fixed.mp4`, the new version will play fine. Don't know if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I have an a MediaElement app that will play MP4 (AVC1) files on a Primary display. However, when I drag the app window from the Primary display to a Secondary display (extended desktop), the video freezes and won't play. The MediaElement throws an "Error: Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D11B1" which I think is the codec dieing.  I have K-Lite codec pack installed so the MediaElement may be using a different codec from your app.

According to this MicroSoft page, AVC should work:
Supported Media Formats, Protocols, and Log Fields
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: FYI `0xC00D11B1` is `NS_E_WMP_FILE_OPEN_FAILED`, Windows Media Player encountered a problem while playing the file.

Comment: This is a different issue to mine. The video plays, but with artifacts (and I can drag it across displays).